# How to properly close winforms application from console application

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I want to properly close winform application from console app. So I try something like this:

```
                var cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                if (runUI)
                {
                    var UI = new FormUI(somedata);

                    //cancel request if form is closing.
                    UI.FormClosing += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        cancelSource.Cancel();
                    };


                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        //run form from console app.
                          Application.Run(UI);

                    }, cancelSource.Token);
                }
```

But when I clicked X button on form I've got null reference exception and I dont know where it was thrown. 
[image]
So how to do it properly?

UPDATE:
To be more clear. My console app just read user commands and then execute some processing data methods. If user write command to show UI I want to open new form and pass data via constructor. These data change so I refresh this form view every 5 seconds. Main purpose is to make data processing independent of the form. But when I close that form, the null reference exception is thrown. Using cancelation is just trying to kill this Task when form is closing.

Following to answer I make something like this:

```
            var data = new Data(...)
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                data.Execute();
            });
            thread.Start();

            if (runUI)
            {
                var UI = new FormUI(data);
                Application.Run(UI);
            }
```

But it still give me error when I close the form.

Comment: Your UI form is being created on the main thread but then you start your message loop on another thread. The creation of a form and its message loop should be on the same thread. If your UI form exits then the Application.Run message loop will also exit, so your thread will exit as well. I don't see why you're needing the cancellation token. If you let us know what your main thread is doing we can give you some pointers on how to make it exit when the ui form closes.

Comment: Console app  pass data via constructor to this form. Form only refresh data every 5 sec and displays it.

Comment: I'd recommend that you simply swap the threads. When the program starts  launch your data thread. Then call Application.Run(UI) on the main program thread. If the data thread is set as a background thread then it will automatically exit when the ui does.

Comment: But I dont want to exit data thread when ui does. UI only displays data. So when I exits UI, I want to data processing still going on.

Comment: Cancellation token won't magically abort the task, what's its purpose here? Also, you didn't post any console code, this code only shows that the `Form` should cancel the token associated with the task where the `Form` is being run (which is also problematic since it was created on a different thread).

Comment: I update post to be more clear.

Comment: You must show the stack trace to provide a hint where the NRE occurred.  The starting point is however very bad, the thread used by the Task class is fundamentally incapable of displaying UI.  It must be a proper Thread, its SetApartmentState() must be called to select STA.  And it needs to be used to display *all* UI, skimping on that buys you enormous trouble when the SystemEvents class starts raising events on the wrong thread.  Trying to bolt-on UI on a non-GUI program never works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with the cancellation logic etc. But if you strucutre your app with the form on the main thread then it's quite simple.

The _dataThread will keep on running despite the form closing.

```
_dataThread = new Thread(MyDataProcessingLoop)
_dataThread.Start()
if(runUI){
    _uiForm = new UIForm();
    Application.Run(_uiForm);
}else{
    Application.Run(); //Keep the application running
}
```

Comment: I updated post to be more clear. I tried your solution but still give me null reference exception.

Comment: Make sure Debug -> Exceptions -> Clr Exceptions -> Thrown is ticked. This will stop execution whenever an exception happens. Inspect your stack track. It's not the closing of your form thats the issue, it's something that either the form is doing around exit, the timer still trying to modify it after exit, the app trying to interact with it after closing. Also you should implement some logging in your application so you dont need to do this guess work.

Comment: You were right. Thank you for letting me know how to check this exception. The problem was that I trying to operate on something that doesnt exsist anymore after closing the form.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.